# How do I get the line and column number of a character at some index in Text View?

Tags: macos, swift, nstextview

I have a `NSTextView` in which I have lots of text.

How can I get the line and the column number of the character at some index?

Lets say, I have this text in the `NSTextView`:

```
"This is just a\ndummy text\nto show you\nwhat I mean."
```

And I need the line and column number for the 16th character. In this case:

```
Line: 2
Column: 2
```

How can I calculate/get this using Swift?

**Another example:**

```
"This is just a\ndummy text\nto show you\nwhat I mean."
```

And I want the line and row number for **15th** (or 16th, if `\n` are counted too) character, like this:

```
Line: 2
Column: 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to break your text lines using String method componentsSeparatedByString, then you just need to keep count of your lines, columns and character position as follow:

```
extension String {
    func characterRowAndLineAt(position: Int) -> (character: String, line: Int, column:Int)? {
        var lineNumber = 0
        var characterPosition = 0
        for line in components(separatedBy: .newlines) {
            lineNumber += 1
            var columnNumber = 0
            for column in line {
                characterPosition += 1
                columnNumber += 1
                if characterPosition == position {
                    return (String(column), lineNumber, columnNumber )
                }
            }
            characterPosition += 1
            if characterPosition == position {
                return ("\n", lineNumber, columnNumber+1 )
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

```
let myText    = "This is just a\ndummy text\nto show you\nwhat I mean."
let result    = myText.characterRowAndLineAt(position: 16) // "(.0 "d", .1 2, .2 1)"
let character = result?.character  // "d"
let line      = result?.line       // 2
let column    = result?.column     // 1
```

Comment: Seems like a poor solution performance wise. You'd have to iterate through the whole text just to find line numbers for a visible section.

Comment: Post you solution if there is an easier/faster way

Comment: I'd query the `NSTextView`'s `NSLayoutManager` and let it enumerate it's cached line fragment rects up to the point of your character range.

Comment: @Era do you have some example code for this?